# Copying a websocket not possible in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

So, I want to move a websocket instance on my Node.js server from one array to the other. I use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(theitem))`, and it sticks in there just fine - but then it gives me a peculiar error.

```
var ws = require("ws");
var server = new ws.Server({server:app.server, path:"/whatever", port:8080})
var clients = [];
var OtherClients = [];
server.on("connection", function(socket){
     socket.send("Hello!"); // This works.
     socket.on("message", function(msg){console.log("whatever");})
     clients.push({socket:socket, OtherInformation:"whatever!"});
     NextFunction();
})

function NextFunction(){
     for(let i = 0; i < clients.length; i+=2){ // Every second one, meant to represent arbitrary logic...
          clients.forEach(TheClient=>{
               TheClient.socket.send("Arbitrary string!"); // This one works.
          })
     }
     OtherClients[0] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clients[clients.length-1]));
     clients.splice(0,1);
     OtherClients[0].socket.send("Another arbitrary string!"); // Crash here.
}
```

This gives me the error `TypeError: OtherClients[0].socket.send is not a function`. How?

Moreover, I noticed that socket.send is not actually a member of the socket object (even in the original version where I can send it). What's going on?

Am I really not allowed to copy a WebSocket object, or am I missing the point *entirely*?

Comment: Hey, It's not gonna work with JSON.stringify cause it's losing context and everything. When you stringify it's not including properties and such, need to try another way on this

Comment: What do you mean by losing context? When I output all properties of the socket using 

`for(var what in ever) {console.log(what, ever[what])}` 

I get the same result as if I did it before using JSON.stringify.

Comment: Well losing context is it's not gonna work the same. It's losing it's functions and every specific as `WebSocket` object

Comment: If you  use Dates, functions, undefined, Infinity, [NaN], RegExps, Maps, Sets, Blobs, FileLists, ImageDatas, sparse Arrays, Typed Arrays or other complex types within your object, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) does not work. I prefer loddash to do deep copy.

Comment: @Nonik - There is no reason at all to make a copy of any kind here.  The OP just needs to remove the object from one array and add it to another.  No copy needed.  My answer below illustrates.

Comment: Regardless helpful, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stringify a webSocket object and then parse it back into a functioning object.  A webSocket object represents a local TCP connection and can't easily be serialized like that.

If you just want to move the socket object from one array to another, you can just take the socket object and add it to another array, no serialization to JSON necessary.  You could do it like this:

```
// remove last socket from clients array and 
// add it to the beginning of the OtherClients array
OtherClients.unshift(clients.pop());
```

Comment: Gotcha. In my mind, a JavaScript object was just a JSON object; meaning it only held data - I wouldn't imagine magic going on behind it's back until it's disposed of. I'll try this.

Comment: @aaaaaahnode - First off, JSON is a plain text serialization format, used to express data that can be converted into a plain Javascript object.  JSON is different than a live Javascript object.  Javascript objects that have native resources behind them (open files, sockets, servers, etc...) aren't JUST Javascript and can't be serialized to JSON in this way.  Plus, in your case, you just want to move the object from one array to another so there's no reason to serialize it in the first place.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time by dispelling my illusion; I was thinking a c-struct that was data only. Does the JavaScript object I showed really have more than just pure JSON *aside* from the functions that got cut out during stringification? Is there binary data, or some memory address or something? I have no idea where to find this information and it just seems interesting, sorry.

Comment: @aaaaaahnode - Well, JSON `stringify()`, then `parse()` only works for plain Javascript objects.  It doesn't work for objects that have a custom class/methods/prototoype or for any object that has a native component in it (like a file handle or socket) as those are not serialized in JSON.

Comment: I know it's annoying to get the question of "Can you link me to explanations of XYZ" when XYZ is easily google-able, but in this case I don't think it is - Is there anywhere you can point me to where I can learn about the JavaScript implementation of objects and the like? I'd especially like to learn about the way it handles its own memory with its garbage collector and the way arrays work - Seeing a video on the chromium bug that allowed RCE on Nintendo's Switch console really got me hungry to see more about that but I've been hard pressed to find anything that isn't a wall of text.